# Database Normalization and Entity-relationship model

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I've created the Entity-relationship model of my database and the I normalized it, but I've a issue, I don't know if after of the normalization I've to create new relations between news tables derived from normalization and the original tables or not.

Comment: can you provide a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "relations", you mean constraints, correct?  :-)  Normalizing a relational database means you broke the tables up to reduce redundancy and dependency.  If you are making more tables, then yes you need to create new constraints (keys).  You'll also need to run a conversion on your database to move the data to the new tables appropriately.